# Mud Blazor Drawer docking

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

New to blazor and MudBlazor,
Can you dock the drawer/sidebar in mudBlazor so that it shows only the icon when minimized?

Like this below

[image]

What I mean is that the sidebar is not totally hidden when the burger icon is toggled but it still shows the icons, currently when toggled the burger menu the sidebar totally dissapears. Is it possible to do that in mudblazor

If possible would you share a snippet?

Comment: Apologies if not clear , what I mean is that the sidebar is not totally hidden when the burger icon is toggled but it still shows the icons, currently when toggled the burger menu the sidebar totally dissapears. Is it possible to do that in mudblazor

Answer (score 1):

Add property Variant="DrawerVariant.Mini"

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you need to use the Variant="DrawerVariant.Mini" in order to create a docked mini drawer: https://mudblazor.com/components/drawer#variants-mini

Also have a look at the customization options for mini drawers, there ae a lot of different ways you can configure the side menu: https://mudblazor.com/components/drawer#mini-drawer-customization